# Keycloak Spring boot before login and programmatic logout

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud, Spring Boot and Keycloak to build an application based on microservices.

For a particular business requirement, I have to use custom login\registration page etc. I am able to create user. But how should I add a small custom logic before login and also, SSO logout of the application programmatically.

Comment: You can create a custom frontend theme (pages) on the KeyCloak side. It's easy. Instruction: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#creating-a-theme

Comment: I know, but as per business requirement we cannot do that.

Comment: Then you need to implement your own authenticator. I tried to describe steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66671012/8397480 
**UPD** It will be much easier to answer your question if I could see all restrictions